# How to change user's & group's folder in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I can't seem to find how to change the default folder where gitlab stores user's and group's info. When I create a user or a group via web, gitlab automatically creates a folder at **/home/git/repositories** for each of them and I would like to have those folders under:

> /home/git/users
>   /home/git/groups

respectively. I checked both gitlab's and gitlab-shell's config.yml file, but they only have an entry for **repos_path**.

Thanks in advance.